# std::move(key) while iterating over unordered_map<string, string>?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

Is the following safe?

```
unordered_map<string, string> my_map;
unordered_map<string, double> new_map;
for(auto&& [key, value] : my_map) {
    new_map.insert({std::move(key), std::stod(value)});
}
```

I'm not using `my_map` after the loop, is it ok to move from the `key` while iterating over it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

No because it does not do what you intend. The key of an `unordered_map` is const-qualified. It cannot be moved from.

Yes because the code is safe and it compiles. The key is simply copied.

This is the same for all ordered and unordered associative containers, including `map`, `set`, `unordered_multiset`, etc.

Comment: is that the case for std::map<> also?

Comment: @AminRoosta See [`std::map`'s `value_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)